# Files deleted from iTunes library don't go to Trash

Tags: macos, itunes, trash

I am running OS X 10.6.7 and iTunes 10.4.

When I delete music or a podcast from the library in iTunes, I get a warning whether I would like to keep or move the file to Trash. I respond that I want to move the file to Trash, however this does not happen. No file is going to Trash.

I have tried updating the software, operating system, repairing disk permissions, none of these work.

Comment: So do the files still physically remain in your library folder after that? Are they visible *within* iTunes?

Comment: they are not visible in the library but the actual file is still in the itunes music folder

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason... is your iTunes library stored on an external drive? (ie. the song files themselves, NOT the iTunes library files that is in your ~/Music folder)

A user can set the default location for all of the MEDIA files onto an external drive and as long as the default library has its location set to this location all should work just as it would if the media files were stored in the user's home directory location. (i.e. ~/Music/iTunes)

IF this drive is either having problems with permissions (more than the likely culprit here) or the drive is not mounted, iTunes will by default use the normal path to the user's home directory and NOT the path specified by the user. Music (or other media) deleted from the main library will NOT get moved to the trash should this be the case. The entry in the XML database for the track is the ONLY thing deleted as it has no reference within it to point to the actual file to delete it.

I use an external 1TB drive to house all of my media files used by iTunes and it works for me as I've got over 60K of tracks in my system and there just isn't enough space on the internal drive of my MacBook to store them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what might cause this strange behavior even across updates and OSes.

You may want to consider resetting the warning boxes. This can be done in Preferences under the "Advanced" tab (on the right). This may reset the settings and flip it back to default behavior.